# Making A Password Key Validator And One Of The Output Should Show: Reports ALL The Rules That The Key Failed

Tags: java, string, validation, if-statement, key

I am making a Password/Key Validator with a set of rules which must be met to validate the Password/Key.

These rules are the following: - The key be at least 7 characters long, AND at most 20 characters long, AND - The key must not start with the special characters '#' or '', AND - The key must not have a space character anywhere, AND - The key must have at least one Upper case character and at least one Lower case character, AND - The key must not contain the user's name, AND - The key must contain either a '#' or a '', but not both.

I have managed to get all the rules to work. There are two outputs that checks the key against the rules and either reports that the key is valid or reports ALL the rules that the key failed.

On the output, I am unable to show/report ALL the rules that the key failed.

The code I currently have is below. I am new to learning java so please understand.

```
 * Asks user for key word and the name and then checks if it is a valid key word.
 */
public void doCompletion(){
    String key = UI.askString("Key:   ");
    String name = UI.askString("Your name:   ");
    this.validateKeyCompletion(key, name);
}

/** COMPLETION
 * Report that the key is valid or report ALL the rules that the key failed.
 */
public void validateKeyCompletion(String key, String name){
    /*# YOUR CODE HERE */
   int characterNumber = key.length();
   boolean hasUppercase;
   boolean hasLowercase;
   hasUppercase = !key.equals(key.toLowerCase());
   hasLowercase = !key.equals(key.toUpperCase());
   String specialChars = "(.*[ #  _  ].*)";
   if (characterNumber < 7 || characterNumber > 20){
    UI.println("Invalid: Key length must not be less than 7 or greater than 20");
   }
   else if (key.contains(" ")){
    UI.println("Invalid: Key cannot contain ' '");
   }
   else if(!hasUppercase)
   {
    UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain an uppercase character");
   }
   else if(!hasLowercase)
   {
    UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain a lowercase character");
   }
   else if(key.matches(name)){
    UI.println("Invalid: Key cannot contain Username");
   }
   else  if(!key.matches("^[^#_]+[#_]{1,1}[^#_]*")) {
    UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain either a '#' or a '_', but not both");
   }
   else {
    UI.println("Valid");
   }


}
```

Comment: change all the `else if` statements into separate `if` statements; otherwise it stops on the first match

Comment: @Gus thank you for your reply. So you are saying that I should just remove all the 'else' and just leave it as 'if'?

Comment: yes, that will make sure all the checks happen.  But, then you'll need to track whether any of the checks failed.  Easiest to add an `isValid=true` before all the checks, and then inside each if clause, set isValid=false.  At the end, if isValid is still true, they all passed

Comment: '@Gus thanks for your reply again. I tried what you said but I had no success. I added isValid=true before all the checks (above the line which started with 'if', and it said that there was no variable found with 'isValid'. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You're pretty close; your  current solution will stop at the first failure case.  Since you want to know all of the cases that fail, you need to keep all the checks separate (not in an if/else if/else if chain).  But, then you need some way to remember if any of the checks have failed to determine a pass/fail at the end.  It's easiest to use a boolean value (let's call it `isValid` for this and set to true at the beginning, and then in each `if` block (that gets triggered when a check has failed), set `isValid` to false.  Then if it fails more than one time, it'll just get set to false a couple of times, but at the end you know at least one of the checks has failed.

```
public void validateKeyCompletion(String key, String name) {
    int characterNumber = key.length();
    boolean isValid = true;  // use this to see if any checks have failed at the end
    boolean hasUppercase;
    boolean hasLowercase;
    hasUppercase = !key.equals(key.toLowerCase());
    hasLowercase = !key.equals(key.toUpperCase());
    if (characterNumber < 7 || characterNumber > 20) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key length must not be less than 7 or greater than 20");
        isValid = false;  // set to false for each check that fails
    }
    if (key.contains(" ")) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key cannot contain ' '");
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!hasUppercase) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain an uppercase character");
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!hasLowercase) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain a lowercase character");
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (key.matches(name)) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key cannot contain Username");
        isValid = false;
    }
    if (!key.matches("^[^#_]+[#_]{1,1}[^#_]*")) {
        UI.println("Invalid: Key must contain either a '#' or a '_', but not both");
        isValid = false;
    }

    // now if isValid is true, we know all the checks passed
    if(isValid) {  
        UI.println("Pass!");
    } else {
        UI.println("Fail!");
    }

}
```